# Trying to fetch the distint result but it does not work using mysqli statement query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch the data from three tables which have many to many relationship. Here is the table structure of my database.

**users**

```
uid[pk] fname lname username
 1      John  smith johnsmith
```

**activity**

```
act_id[pk] title
 log       Account Login
 reg       Account Registration
```

**user_activity**

```
serial_number[pk] act_id[fk] user_id[fk] ip_address date time
1                  reg           1       2.2.2.2      - 
2                  log           1       1.1.1.1      -
```

I am trying to fetch:

```
title  ip_address date time
```

Here is my mysqli query statement:

```
SELECT a.title, ua.ip_address, ua.date, ua.time FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN user_activity ua ON ua.user_id = u.uid 
LEFT JOIN activity a ON a.activity_id = ua.act_id 
WHERE u.username=?"
```

It fetches the data from the database and i am getting 3 results instead of just 1:

```
Title            Ip_address      Date                Time

Account Login    1.1.1.1         Mon,Nov4 2013       5:5pm
Account Login    1.1.1.1         Mon,Nov4 2013       5:5pm
Account Login    1.1.1.1         Mon,Nov4 2013       5:5pm
```

I used DISTICT but it does not work. Please make me correct if i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: How did you try to use DISTINCT?

Comment: I tried to use it right after `SELECT` keyword

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Did you get duplicate results? No results? The wrong results?

Comment: i am getting duplicate results

Comment: What are the values in your table for date and time? Is it an actual date and time, or a `-`, as in your question?

Comment: Both values for date and time are strings.

Comment: But what _are_ the values? Can you edit your question so it's got all the results from your query in it, rather than just the title and IP address?

Comment: Actually the above query works fine but repeats the results 3 times.

Comment: Edited my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to add a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
  title, ip_address
FROM
  users AS u
LEFT JOIN
  user_activity AS ua ON ua.user_id = u.uid
LEFT JOIN
  activity AS a ON a.activity_id = ua.act_id 
WHERE
  u.username = ?
GROUP BY
  ua.ip_address
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it myself. Now its working fine. Here is the query.

```
SELECT a.title, ua.ip_address, ua.date, ua.time
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN user_activity AS ua ON ua.user_id = u.uid
LEFT JOIN activity AS a ON a.activity_id = ua.act_id
WHERE u.username = 'johnsmith'
GROUP BY ua.serial_number
```